# acts_as_taggable_on find existing tags to suggest from content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, autosuggest, acts-as-taggable-on

We're using the (brilliant) acts_as_taggable_on Rails gem, allowing users to add tags to content they write (e.g. blog comment).  We auto-suggest on as they type, but would also like to identify tags that we can suggest based on the user's content.

So if the user typed "We really loved the aquarium in Boston" and we had existing tags for "boston" and "aquarium" we might suggest those.

I think this is simple conceptually (iterate words, check the tags list, order by frequency of use), but there are little nuances, performance implications, and well, you know -- always harder than it looks.

Any suggestions for existing code or examples that might help me avoid recreating a wheel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't really know acts_as_taggable... But I think you can use something like :

```
  Tag.find(:all, :conditions => { :name => title.split(' ').map(&:downcase) })
```

Comment: Thanks!  Well, yes, this handles the main case, and -- as with all RoR, it's lovely and simple. I think we'll need some more complicated processing since we allow multi-word tags ("New York Times"), which is nice for users.  We may end up going the other way, mapping tags against the content, but same basic idea.  The other concern is that the finder query results in an entry in the SQL in clause for each word of the content, which for people like me who write a lot of words could get hard on our database server :-).  Still hoping someone might have already done this.

Comment: If you index your tag database, there will be no problem about performance. What's more, multi-word tags can be added to the conditions array generating all sequences of word. But that's really hard and greedy.

Comment: To be sure, the performance issue is only real at scale.  The bi-gram and n-gram problems are a little more complicated than that, methinks.  Yes, the name column is indexed, but in our case we're talking about potentially 10K or more unique tags, and content containing between 50 and 500 words, with probably 100 being the mode -- so assuming we cache the tags keyed by name, and pre-process the content to remove low-value words (stop words) we ... well, you get the idea.  It's not trivial at scale, nor rocket science -- I was really just hoping someone would know of an existing thing :-)  Thx!